# Listing future posts together with normal posts

Tags: custom-post-types, events

In my blog I'm displaying lists of posts from every category I have in the homepage. I have a column for each category. The code is this:

```
<?php
$categories = array('3', '4', '5');

foreach ($categories as $category):
?>
        <div class="four columns">
            <h2 id="first_column" class="category_title"><?php echo  get_the_category_by_ID($category); ?></h2>
        <div class="post-list">
<?php 
global $post;
$args = array('numberposts' => '3', 'category' => $category, 'post_status' => array('publish', 'future' ));
$myposts = get_posts($args);
```

Now I'd need to display also posts occurring in the future. They are called events, I guess. I know I cannot use the wordpress status flag of the posts, because it has another purpose.

I also tried the Event Manager plugin, but I can't find any way to mix these custom posts with the normal ones.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you created a custom post type? That isn't completely clear.

Comment: The [Event Manager plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/) creates a custom post type. I just have no clue how to display these posts mixed with the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [post type parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) to your `get_posts` args.

```
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => '3', 
  'category' => $category, 
  'post_status' => array('publish', 'future' )
  'post_type' => array('post','slug-for-the-event-manager-post-type')
);

$myposts = get_posts($args);
```